# silverlight mailmessage embedde image is gray

Tags: silverlight, image, mailmessage

My silverlight application is supposed to send an e-mail at some point to the preset e-mail address.
So far so good, it actually sends the e-mail.

My problem starts when I want to embed an image. This is one of many sample codes I'm actually using:

```
            string Body = "<b>This is a test E-Mail</b><br><BR>This E-mail is being sent as part of beta testing...<BR><img alt=\"\" src=\"cid:imageId\"  >";
            ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body, null, "text/html");
            LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(@"C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Projectos\\WorkIt\\Resources\\Imagens\\workitlogosmall.jpg", ct);
            imagelink.ContentId = "imageId";
            imagelink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

I'm receiving the e-mail with the text formatted, but instead of the image, I get a gray box.

What's going on? I've tried different approaches to get the path for the image, but always with the same result!!

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it... I've solved the issue.

It has nothing to do with with the code, the code WORKS fine.

The e-mail account that I'm using to receive the email's is one of my oldest and I don't use it that often, so I've completely forgotten that I had the "Show Content" deactivated for every mail that I receive (duh) and that's why it blocked the image I was sending.

I actually felt pretty stupid after realizing that.

Anyway, hope this helps anyone who is as distracted as I am :)